# How do you return GraphQL elements that are empty or have no value?

Tags: graphql

What's the recommended way to return the value of an element with no value?  Do you exclude it from the selection list or set it to null/none?  Irrespective, what's the best way to code this from the client's perspective?

```
try {
  display (obj.name, obj.val);
} catch(e)
{
  log(e);
}
```

or

```
if obj.name && obj.val
  display(obj.name, obj.val);
```